# AWS ECS Fargate Task: Set request timeout using AWS UI

Tags: java, docker, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have created an ECS Fargate service with a task where my Java-Springboot application is deployed. When I'm calling an endpoint of my application, I'm getting a request canceled (timeout) error in one minute.

Is there any way I can increase the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a load balancer in front of your ECS service, and you need to adjust the default [connection timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout) of the load balancer.